# Is it bad to have a 'coming soon' page before launch?

Tags: seo

I bought a domain name and for the moment the page only says something like 'this domain is registered' but does it have a negative impact on SEO if I keep this page for some months, before I'm ready to launch the website? Will Google blacklist the website because it considers that it has no content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be fine, but there's a couple of things to keep in mind.

If you simply own the domain name but don't have a web host yet, no action needs to be taken. You just own a name (which is essentially a mask for whatever server address you're going to have someday), there's no website, so there's nothing to rank. In this scenario, you can sit on it until you're ready to use it.

If you have a web hosting environment instance that points to your domain name, now you have a website, even if there's nothing there. You have to make sure that your `robots.txt` file disallows all legitimate web crawlers. Do the following:

1. Log into your web host's c-panel, or FTP into it.
2. Check if a `robots.txt` file exists at the root. It should look like this:

   `User-agent: * 
    Disallow: /`
3. If it's anything other than that, update it. The directive above will disallow your whole domain from being crawled, starting at the root. If a `robots.txt` doesn't exist, create one and upload it to the root. (Just don't forget to update it when you set the site live!)
4. While the above will keep your domain from being crawled, make sure you don't start promoting the site before there's at least a splash page. You don't want the indexing to begin until there's something to be seen. Refrain listing your domain on any blogs, in ads, or on social media until then.

As far as splash pages and maintenance modes, see points 1 and 2 of my response in this thread, as they're relevant here:

[How to close a website for a few months without affecting SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/107036/how-to-close-a-website-for-a-few-months-without-affecting-seo/107037#107037)

Comment: Ok, but now I wonder if it would not be more efficient to have a 'coming soon' page that contains some information about what the website will contain. Won't the SEO be more efficient if the website already exist since a long time? Because if I disallow the indexing, I will have to start from zero when I'll launch the site, instead of benefiting from months of existence, am I wrong?

Comment: You're not wrong. It's a perfectly common marketing tactic to have a Coming Soon page, let it return a 200 server response, put some info and text, maybe a contact form, social media buttons... Make sure it can be crawled and indexed... And when you go live, hook up Google Search Console, and submit your new site to be re-indexed.

Answer (score 2):

Google will not 'blacklist' you per se-- many times this is just done on behalf of the hosting company.

However, I think putting up a small page with basic business info is much better than a hosted domain site holder as you can start to give Googlebot and other search engines an idea about what the future pages/site will contain if you or someone on your web team has enough time to make something that can start doing very basic business conversions (ex. similar to what giving out a business card might do-- ex.: address, phone number,  products and/or services).

Duplicate content is also frowned upon in SEO (search engine optimizations) so if the domain page holder exactly matches other sites and isn't returning a proper HTTP response code or meta data to make the search engines understand the site is temporary-- that could put the site in a slight disadvantage.

I also do believe that Google advises against putting up 'Under Construction' type pages as it is the very nature of websites to be updated often. Distracting graphics and UI distractions are unnecessary.

Here's Google's starter guide: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7451184?hl=en