# Can showing maintenance page during deployment affect SEO?

Tags: seo, azure, availability

I have an Azure App Service web application.

I have big traffic 24h and this is a problem when it comes to deploy. The definitive solution would be to bring the application deployment downtime to 0, but as a quick solution for the next deployment I want to display a maintenance page during the deploy downtime.

I'd like to display the maintenance page ad described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49930116/7130614) stack overflow answer, but, does redirecting the application to a different URL for a short period of time can have a negative impact on the site's SEO?

Comment: Answers in the somewhat similar question below may be relevant here as well; see my bullets on temporarily putting your site in maintenance mode: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/107036/how-to-close-a-website-for-a-few-months-without-affecting-seo/107037#107037

Answer (score 3):

I don't have specific experience with Azure App Service, but if you can, I would recommend *rewriting* the page so that the original URL itself displays the maintenance page with a `503 Service Unavailable` status code, rather than issuing a redirect that takes the user to a separate "maintenance page URL". This plays more nicely with the user's browser in terms of forward/back/refresh/history/bookmarking, and it's easier to reason about in terms of HTTP spec and SEO.

[From Google](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/pause-online-business#disable-site):

> If you need to urgently disable the site for 1-2 days, then return an informational error page with a 503 HTTP response status code instead of all content.

Of course, your downtime for a deploy should be a lot less than 1-2 days, but the principle stands that a `503 Service Unavailable` status code is the best way to tell crawlers to hang tight and that the website will be back up and servicing requests soon. When the Google crawler sees a URL with a `503` status code it will come back later to check on that URL again, and by that time your site should be done with its deploy. According to Google, their bot will continue to retry `503`'d urls [for up to about a week](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2017/02/closing-down-for-day), so if your server is unable to serve content normally for a short amount of time, serving a `503` status code can only help.

Comment: *Docker & Kuberneties entered the chat*